# ASP.NET Web Forms website build error

Tags: asp.net, webforms, vs-web-site-project

As I try to build this project, I keep coming up with an error.

Description, where the eight '*' are always something different with every build:

> An error occurred when merging assemblies: ILMerge.Merge: ERROR!!: Duplicate type 'myTypeName' found in assembly 'App_Web_********'.

and the file is

> aspnet_merge

What do I need to do in order to resolve this (annoying) error?

Comment: Does it actually say `Duplicate type '<>'` verbatim, or is there a type-name inside the angle-brackets?

Comment: There is a type-name inside. I will edit that for clarity

Comment: I'm guessing your WebForms project is referencing another WebForms project or otherwise references another project in the same solution or has code in `App_code` that is messing it up. Does the website build fine without using the merge step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things you can try is after right clicking on your project, select **Publish Web App**. Then under settings (settings for me, might be different for you), find your **File Publish Options** and click **Configure**. You'll see the dialog below.

Try the first or second option, *Do not merge* OR *Do not merge. Create a separate assembly for each page and control*

[image]

I know this is something that has plagued me in the past so good luck. Update us if you find any better or if something better works for you.